# What is the name of the old manual sizing tool for measuring photos, to be used in offset printing?

Tags: photo-editing, tools, crop

Years ago, before computers took over, I worked with a photo cropping tool; I hope someone can tell me its name.

The gizmo I used was for sizing photos so they could be used in offset printing. They were never sliced physically. I marked them with a grease pen.

It was made of a soft metal, and it was in an open accordion shape, so it expanded and contracted. When opened up, it looked like a bunch of lower-case x's like so:

## xxxxxxxx

There were numbers on it corresponding to inches that you used to gauge how big you wanted the photo to be so you could size things.

I have hunted for a picture but can't find one. Any help is much appreciated.

**Does anyone know the name of the tool I have described?**

Comment: You mean the cropping tool or "cropping L" It looked just like the icon for cropping in Photoshop right? It was just a crop tool as far as I remember.

Comment: Do you mean that little square thing? No, that's not it. But thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a "Pantograph?"

Comment: if you can sketch it in any way you will get the picture in minutes from us

Comment: Pantograph was/is for drawing duplication, not cropping.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means scrissors.

Comment: You mean the thingy that was attached to a drawing/cutting/lightbox table?

Comment: Despite asking this in graphic design, I am not a graphic artist; I am a writer. If you Google "wooden expandable coat rack," you'll see lots of examples of the design of the sort of thing I mean, if not the function! It was a free-standing tool and might have been unique to the Boston area. Again, thank you all for your ideas.

Comment: Is 'adjustable easel' or 'masking frame' what you are looking for? See my updated answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, this thing helped in cropping _paper_ (ie. physical photographs) as in _cutting_, or was it a visual guide for _taking_ pictures?

Comment: The gizmo I used was for sizing photos so they could be used in offset printing. They were never sliced physically. I marked them with a grease pen.

Answer (score 6):

### A analogue photo cropping tool is a Scaleograph

I used Google and the query: 'analogue photo cropping tool'.

[image: Photo cropping tool / Scaleograph]

Scource: http://tinytutorials.wordpress.com/2013/12/02/cropping-tool-scaleograph/

### Update: adjustable easel or masking frame

In a dark room a *adjustable easel* or *masking frame* is used as 'margin locator' and 'automatic paper holding system'. The position of a masking frame on a *base board* in combination and the distance of the *enlarger head* defines the position and size of projected image. Therefore this could be considered a cropping tool. But it won't change the paper size. You need a knife and rulers or photo cutter for that.

[image: Adjustable easel]

[image: Masking frame]

Source: https://www.etsy.com/market/darkroom/

Comment: I used to use a Brandt Scalograph when I was a layout editor for a high school yearbook in the early 1980's.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the tool that's being looked for, but I don't know the name either.
[image]

Comment: that's a [Pantograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantograph)

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I'll answer it anyway. It's called a pantograph.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantograph

Answer (score -1):

It is called an Equal Spacing Divider

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations, with images if necessary. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.